# What does the word "as" mean as in the following sentence? " shall be made as will... "

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What does the word ***as*** mean in the following sentence?

> Such preparations shall be made **as** will completely obscure all Federal buildings and non-Federal buildings occupied by the Federal government during an air raid for any period of time from visibility by reason of internal or external illumination

Comment: Please tell us the source of this text.  Ideally please link to the text. The word "as" seems to be an error.

Comment: It is rather a verbose way to say, "Turn all the lights out"!

Comment: Haha,right , it's an indeed verbose way to say "Turn all the lights out."

Comment: The source of this text comes from page 8 of the book "On writing well" by William Zinsser.

Answer (score 2):

The word **as** is the completion of the formula **Such....as**.

**Such** can mean "of this kind/type".

**Such farms as have sheep:** *The kind of farms that have sheep*, or *Those farms which have sheep*.

**Such men as have swords:** *Those men who have swords.*

> So
>
> **Such** preparations shall be made **as** will completely obscure...
>
> means
>
> **The type of** preparations shall be made **which** will completely obscure...
>
> Or
>
> **Those** preparations shall be made **which** will completely obscure...

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has been very helpful as I understand well now.

Comment: You're welcome, Ken. Glad it helped.